# Angular API call fails in MEAN application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

In a MEAN app I am trying to allow an authorised user (email and password login) to change their username.
I can successfully use Postman to PUT a new username to http://localhost:3000/api/users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
But the angular code fails.
Here is the relevant part of the edit page:

```
<form ng-submit="user.saveUser()">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label> New Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.userData.name">
            </div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
.controller('userEditController', function($routeParams, User) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.type = 'edit';


  User.get($routeParams.user_id)
    .success(function(data) {
      vm.userData = data;
    });

  // function to save the user
  vm.saveUser = function() {
    vm.processing = true;
    vm.message = '';

    // call the userService function to update 
    User.update($routeParams.user_id, vm.userData)
      .success(function(data) {
        vm.processing = false;

        // clear the form
        vm.userData = {};

        // bind the message from our API to vm.message
        vm.message = data.message;
      });
  };


});
```

Here is the service:

```
// update a user
    userFactory.update = function(id, userData) {
        return $http.put('/api/users/' + id, userData);
    };
```

at this point userData contains *name: “Fred”* or whatever was input to the form

and here is the api.js

```
apiRouter.route('/users/:user_id')

        // get the user with that id
        .get(function(req, res) {
            User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.user_id, function(err, user) {
                if (err)  return res.send(err);

                // return that user
                res.json(user);
            });
        })

        // update the user with this id
        .put(function(req, res) {
                console.error(req.params.user_id);
            User.findById(req.params.user_id, function(err, user) {

                if (err) return res.send(err);

                // set the new user information if it exists in the request
                if (req.body.name) user.name = req.body.name;

                // save the user
                user.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) return res.send(err);

                    // return a message
                    res.json({ message: 'User updated!' });
                });

            });
        });
```

(I had to use findByIdAndUpdate instead of findById because of a CastError.)

Although the console states:

XHR finished loading: PUT http:/localhost/3000/api/users/user_id

The value of req.params.user_id is just *user_id*.

The terminal shows:

PUT /api/users/user_id 200 4.040 ms - 2273

GET /api/users/user_id - - ms - -

GET /api/users/user_id - - ms - -

GET /api/users/user_id - - ms - -

Like I say Postman can communicate with the API and can update without problems. I am stumped, and hopefully someone will put me out of my misery

Comment: Why are you using both get and put function. You can simply pass the user id  to put request and update data by using findByIdAndUpdate

Comment: If I remove the get function I get a "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name'" when anything is entered in the edit form.

Comment: Also changing findById to findByIdAndUpdate in the put messes up the ability of Postman to update via the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change tack with this one. The fact that a manually entered user_id in Postman worked should have told me that the user_id provided by the Angular code  was not correct. So I made sure that the JWT included the user_id:

```
var token = jwt.sign({
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
                user_id: user._id
```

Then added an api endpoint to get user information:

```
apiRouter.get('/me', function(req, res) {
        res.send(req.decoded);
    });
```

Then connected a service:

```
userFactory.get = function() {
        return $http.get('/api/me/');
    };
```

Then in the controller I could call get:

```
User.get()
  .success(function(result) {
    $scope.user_id = result.user_id;
    });
```

$scope.user_id now has the correct user_id which I can pass into the update method:

```
User.update($scope.user_id, vm.userData)
      .success(function(data)
```

So now it works as intended.